# boto3: How to Find Prefix of S3 Object and Update Object Given the Filename?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a populated S3 bucket and a filename I want to search for and update. The bucket has an existing list of objects (with prefixes). I am trying to make an API call to the bucket to update a given object. However, I need to search through all the objects in the bucket (including all prefixes), and then update it (via an s3 file upload) if it matches the current filename.

For example, my bucket has the following in root:

```
cat2.jpg
cat3.jpg
PRE CAT_PICS/cat.jpg
PRE CAT_PICS/cat2.jpg
PRE CAT_PICS/MORE_CAT_PICS/cat3.jpg
```

If I want to "recursively" search through all objects, match, and update `cat3.jpg` how could I do that? Additionally, is there a way to extract the prefix of the found object? I have some code already but I am not sure if it is correct. It also cannot cover more than 1000 objects since it lacks pagination:

My Current Code:

```
import boto3

FILE_TO_UPDATE = cat3.jpg

s3_bucket = "example_bucket2182023"
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")

for my_bucket_object in my_bucket.objects.all():
    if my_bucket_object.endswith(FILE_TO_UPDATE):
        try:
            s3_client.put_object(
                Bucket=s3_bucket,
                key=my_bucket_object
            )
        except:
            print(f"Error uploading {my_bucket_object} to {s3_bucket}")

    print(my_bucket_object.key)
```

Comment: Your code is not syntactically valid. That aside, if you want to find all S3 object keys with a given suffix e.g. cat3.jpg then you have no choice but to enumerate all object keys. Recommend you use the resource-level  [Bucket](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#bucket) interface to remove the need for pagination.

Comment: @jarmod aside from syntax, what is actually missing in my approach?

Comment: Your approach, broadly, is valid although your call to put_object is invalid. BTW you already appear to be using the resource-level Bucket so explicit pagination should not be required. If you feel otherwise, then please post the actual code, not something close to it.

Answer (score 0):

For pagination, you can use `get_paginator()` from boto3 S3 client. See reference here: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/paginators.html#customizing-page-iterators

Comment: Your answer does not answer the question "how can I search through all objects, match, and update (a given filename such as) cat3.jpg?"